# Geometric Sequence Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

A worker at a scrapbook sticker company increases her productivity of stickers by 10% every day for a period of days. If she produced 100 stickers in the first day how many stickers did she produce on her third day?

How would you express her pattern of productivity as a sequence of the form an = ?; where an is the number of stickers produced on day n.

I understand the geometric sequence to be $a_n = a \cdot r^{n-1}$, so I thought it would be $100\cdot 0.1^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please tell us what you have already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: ok so i understand the geometric sequence to be a to the subscript n= a*r^n-1

Comment: So i thought it would be 100*.1^2

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  An increase of $10\%$ is represented by multiplying the quantity by $1.1$.

Comment: Can you explain why that is>

Comment: If you start with $100$, the increase is $0.1 \cdot 100=10$  The new value is then $100+10=110$  You can represent this as initial value $*(1+\frac {increase percent}{100})$

Answer (score 0):

If this is too abstract, you can calculate the first few days explicitly and try to see a pattern then. On the first day it is 100. On the second day it is 10% more. That means you have all of what was produced on the day before (=100) and an additional 10% (=100*0.1). That totals 110 for the second day.

You do the same for the third day: The production of the previous day is 110 and the additional 10% of that is 110*0.1=11. In total 121 for the third day.

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Thank you guys so much this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

On the first day, $100$. On the second day, $110$, obviously (which is $100 + 100 \times 10\%$). The third day is more interesting: $121$, which is $110 + 110 \times 10\%$. The fourth day will be $133.1$ (i.e. $121 + 121 \times 10\%$).

To make the pattern more obvious, we factor the sums: $100 + 100 \times 10\% = 100 \ (1 + 10\%) = 100 \times 1.10$. Then $121 = 110 \times 1.10 = 100 \times 1.10 \times 1.10 = 100 \times 1.10^2$. And similarly $133.1 = 100 \times 1.10^2\times 1.10= 100 \times 1.10^3$.

More generally on the $n^{th}$ day, $1.10^{n-1}$.

---

A more interesting pattern is when you look at the digits of the powers of $1.1$:

$$1\\1.\ 1\\1.\ 2\ 1\\1.\ 3\ 3\ 1\\1.\ 4\ 6\ 4\ 1\\\cdots$$

You may recognize [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), in which every digit is the sum of the two ones immediately above it.